# What's the difference of <T>(a: T) => U and <a: T> => U in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

As stated in the title, if I have a function declared as below:

```
applyTo<T, U>(a: T): (a: T) => U
```

Call the function:

```
applyTo(1)(x => x + '2')
```

The TypeScript will show you an error:

```
TS2345:Argument of type '(b: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

Change the declare of `applyTo` function as below code which will fix the error:

```
applyTo<T, U>(a: T): <T>(a: T) => U
```

I dont't know why? Can you tell me their differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing implementation would make things more clear but the signature ...

```
applyTo<T, U>(a: T): (a: T) => U
```

says: "Give me some **T** and I'll give you back a ***function*** that takes some other **T** as parameter and returns some **U**." so you are supposed to pass as argument something of the same type T, like in:

```
applyTo(1)(2) // -> the result must be some U
```

Since in the first call a number were passed as argument, the compiler expected another number and not a function from (x: whatever) => x + '2'.

The second signature ...

```
applyTo<T, U>(a: T): <T>(a: T) => U
```

can be confusing just because naming, **T** in (a: T) => U is not necessarily the same type T in (a: T): ..., so would be better if each parameter and type parameter had a distinct name:

```
applyTo<T, U>(a: T): (b: T) => U
applyTo<T, U>(a: T): <S>(b: S) => U
```

Now the second signature say's: "Give me some **T** and I'll give back a ***function*** that takes some **S** as parameter and returns some **U**"

So depending on the implementation this would be valid:

```
applyTo(1)        (x => x + '2')  =   ... 
//  ^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
//  T is number   S is function       U is whatever;
//                from whatever to 
//                string
```

Comment: According to your answer and my understanding, `(a: T): U` the **T** is not same as the **T** at `applyTo<T, U>`. Isn't it?

Comment: In the first signature they are the same type T,  so the same letter _must_ be used. In the second signature, the  second angle brackets <T> is signing  a new parameter type, that might not be the same previous T type and that's why it was changed to S.